# Linearization of nonlinear state equation around working points

Tags: nonlinear-system

I'm confused about equilibrium points and operating points, are they two different things or the same thing?

How would one (or what are the steps to) solve the following equation if operating points are given: $x_{10}=1$ , $x_{20}=2$?
$$$$

$\dot{x_1}=e^{x_1}-x_2+u$

$\dot{x_2}=2x_1-x_2$

$y=x_1^2+x_2^2$

Comment: Sorry about that, wrong literal translation. I meant operating points.

Comment: Google helps after the correction: "...about a specific operating point, called an equilibrium point."